# Conditional formatting on Access form looking up a value

Tags: forms, ms-access

I've created a form within Access which uses a cross-tab query as its data source.
The column headings for the query are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 representing week numbers.
The values display items such as **3/3 = 100.00%** or **0/13 = 0.00%** or **3/14 = 21.00%**.

I've added conditional formatting to the text boxes on the form.
`Expression Is Right([2],7)="100.00%"` works and displays the figure in bold red when the percentage is 100.
`Expression is Val(Right([2],7))=100` also works - converting the text value to a numeric value.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not always looking for 100% - it depends on the value within a table.  What I'm trying to do is

- `Val(Right([2],7))=(SELECT ParamValue*100 FROM tbl_System WHERE Param='SampleSize')` - this doesn't work.

Neither does:

- `Eval(Val(Right([2],7))=(SELECT ParamValue*100 FROM tbl_System WHERE Param='SampleSize'))`
  or
- `Val(Right([2],7))=EVAL(SELECT ParamValue*100 FROM tbl_System WHERE Param='SampleSize')`
  or
- `Val(Right([2],7))=DLookUp("ParamValue","tbl_System","Param= 'SampleSize'")*100`
  or
- `Val(Right([2],7))=Eval(DLookUp("ParamValue","tbl_System","Param= 'SampleSize'")*100)`

The SQL for the cross-tab query is:

```
TRANSFORM   NZ(Sum(Abs([Include])),0) & "/" & NZ(Count(*),0) & " = " & 
                FormatPercent(NZ(Round(Sum(Abs(Include))/Count(*),2),0),2)
SELECT      tbl_TMP_PrimaryDataSelection.TeamMember
FROM        tbl_TMP_PrimaryDataSelection
GROUP BY    tbl_TMP_PrimaryDataSelection.TeamMember
PIVOT       tbl_TMP_PrimaryDataSelection.WeekNum In (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use a function in there, be it system or user-defined.

*But* you can define the FormatCondition dynamically at runtime, like this:

```vb
Dim txtFld As TextBox
Dim objFrc As FormatCondition
Dim strExpr As String

Set txtFld = Me!myTextBox
' Remove existing FormatConditions
txtFld.FormatConditions.Delete
' The dynamic expression
strExpr = "Val(Right([2],7))=" & DLookUp("ParamValue","tbl_System","Param='SampleSize'")*100
' Assign a new FormatCondition to text box
Set objFrc = txtFld.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , strExpr)
' Set the format
objFrc.ForeColor = &HFF0000
```

This example simply removes and recreates all FormatConditions. If you have a fixed number of conditions, you can also use the `FormatCondition.Modify` method (see online help).

**Edit:**
The final code I have used executes on the `Form_Load` event and adds a format to each of the five weekly text boxes:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim aTxtBox(1 To 5) As TextBox
    Dim x As Long
    Dim oFrc As FormatCondition
    Dim sExpr As String

    With Me
        Set aTxtBox(1) = .Wk1
        Set aTxtBox(2) = .Wk2
        Set aTxtBox(3) = .Wk3
        Set aTxtBox(4) = .Wk4
        Set aTxtBox(5) = .Wk5

        For x = 1 To 5
            aTxtBox(x).FormatConditions.Delete
            sExpr = "Val(Right([" & x & "],7))>=" & DLookup("ParamValue", "tbl_System", "Param='SampleSize'") * 100
            Set oFrc = aTxtBox(x).FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , sExpr)
            oFrc.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit 2**

Yes, defining FormatConditions via VBA is especially useful when dealing with multiple controls in a loop. You can do this in **Design View** too and save the FormatConditions permanently, simply to avoid going through the FormatConditions dialogs one by one. Or if the customer later decides that he'd rather have a different color. :)

Note: You could use `Set aTxtBox(x) = Me("Wk" & x)` in the loop. But actually you don't need multiple TextBox variables, you can simply re-use it.

Comment: Thank you Andre, that worked perfectly.  I added it to the `Form_Load` event and formatted each text box.  I'll add my final code at the bottom of your answer.