# MS Access Toggle Condition for conditional formatting

Tags: ms-access, formatting

I have conditional formatting turned on, but I want a checkbox that turns the formatting off/on in a subform.  I can get the formatting to turn off, but not sure how to turn back on... Here's what I got so far in code builder:

```
Private Sub Check23_Click()
If Forms!FarmerPartsEditableF!Check23 = True Then
    Me![FarmerPartsListT Subform].Form![Pulsation].FormatConditions.Delete

Else   What Do I put here to turn it back on?

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create FormatConditions at runtime, just like you can delete them. Look up `FormatConditions.Add` in the Online help.

Here is an example: [Conditional formatting on Access form looking up a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067871/conditional-formatting-on-access-form-looking-up-a-value/35069630#35069630)

And here you will find more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ms-access]+FormatConditions.Add

Comment: If I have two rules set up via "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager", can I just delete the one rule when I click on a checkbox?  Sorry I'm a newbie.   I'm bad at building code.  What I got above was after hours of searching and trial and error.  Every time I try to use the add function, I mess something up and it usually tells me that it can't find txtbox or it is invalid.

Comment: Nevermind, I would still have the same issue.  I'm wanting background color of my individual cells to turn on/off based on value in the cells.  This is the last thing I need to do to finish my program, so I'm getting desperate and I have tried for hours on trying to figure out the add or modify feature, but I'm not getting anywhere.    Here's the farthest I think I've gotten: 
        Me[FarmerPartsListTSubform].Form[Pulsation].FormatConditions.Add acFieldValue, _acEqual, Me![txtTarget].Value)

What is txtTarget? and do I need to change acFieldValue in the code?

Comment: @Matudavis: Please edit your question. Add screenshots (or imgur links to them) of both your format conditions. Add a short description of what they are doing. Then I can help with the code.